# Regex to capture string between quotes especially when the string starts with a quote

Tags: python, regex

I have a string as given below.

```
string= 'Sam007's Helsen007' is a 'good' boy's in 'demand6's6'.
```

I want to extract the string inside the quotes.

The output should looks like,

```
['Sam007's Helsen007', 'good', 'demand6's6']
```

The regex I have written in :

```
re.findall("(?:[^a-zA-Z0-9]*')(.*?)(?:'[^a-zA-Z0-9*])", text)
```

But this gives output

```
["Sam007's Helsen007", 'good', "s in 'demand6's6"]
```

when I use modify the regex to

```
re.findall("(?:[^a-zA-Z0-9]')(.*?)(?:'[^a-zA-Z0-9*])", text)
```

It gives me an output:

```
['good', "demand6's6"]
```

The second case seems more appropriate, but it cant handle the case if a string is starting with a quote.

How can I handle the case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
st= "'Sam007's Helsen007' is a 'good' boy's in 'demand6's6'"


print re.findall(r"\B'.*?'\B",st)
```

Use `\B` i.e `non word boundary`

Output:`["'Sam007's Helsen007'", "'good'", "'demand6's6'"]`

If you look carefully through your string you want a string `'` which has a non word character before and `'` which has a non word character after.

Comment: But I think you should also add some explanation so even non-regex users might understand what you were doing actually